# CSS flexbox issue with paragraph

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an issue with my flexbox and text it doesn't follow like the navigation bar in the mobile view. I want it to fill the screen with text the same size as the menu.

Issue:

[image]

I want to look like my `article-container` so that the text is filled out across the whole mobile screen. In desktop view, they are three together and in mobile view, they are stacked like hamburger similar to the menu where it says Länk 1 2 3 4.

[image]

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 25%;
 background-color: #EBEBEB;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}
li a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
li a.active {
 background-color: #F16529;
 color: white;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}
.container {
 margin-left: 25%;
 padding: 1px 16px;
 height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1px 16px;
 }
 div.item {
  width: initial;
  max-width: 256px;
 }
}
div.item {
 vertical-align: top;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 256px;
}
.blog {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
}
.caption {
 display: block;
}
img {
 display: block;
}
img.wrap {
 max-width: 70%;
 margin: 30px 0px;
}
img.align-right {
 float: right;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
div.article-container {
 padding: 5px;
}
.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
footer {
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 1rem;
 background-color: #EBEBEB;
 text-align: center;
}
@media(max-width:767px) {
 img.align-right {
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
 }
 div.article-container {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 256px;
 }
}
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-grid .col {
  flex: 1;
}
.flex-grid-thirds {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-grid-thirds .col {
  width: 32%;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .flex-grid,
  .flex-grid-thirds {
    display: block;
    .col {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
  }
}




* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.flex-grid {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Inlämningsuppgift 6</title>
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <!--nav bar-->
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li style="list-style: none"><br></li>
   <li><img alt="htmll logo" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"></li>
   <li>
    <h2>Menu</h2>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="active" href="#lank">Länk 1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#lank2">Länk 2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#lank3">Länk 3</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#lank4">Länk 4</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav><!--navbar end-->
 <!--container for blog posts 3 images-->

 </div>
 <div class="container">

  <h1>Innehåll</h1>
  <div class="flex-grid-thirds">
   <div class="col">
       <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alligment >
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div><!--end-->
 <hr>
 <!--container for article -->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="article-container clearfix">
   <img alt="html logo" class="wrap align-right" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
   <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
   <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
 </div><!--end-->
 <footer class="container">
  Skriven i HTML 5.
 </footer>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating the width of the `.col` sections in your media query using `.col` but you defined the initial width using `.flex-grid-thirds .col`. So it's just a specificity issue in your media query. Use `.flex-grid-thirds .col` in your media query selector.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #F16529;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 25%;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px 16px;
  }
  div.item {
    width: initial;
    max-width: 256px;
  }
}

div.item {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 256px;
}

.blog {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

img.wrap {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 30px 0px;
}

img.align-right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

div.article-container {
  padding: 5px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  text-align: center;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  img.align-right {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
  }
  div.article-container {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 256px;
  }
}

.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-grid .col {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-grid-thirds {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-grid-thirds .col {
  width: 32%;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .flex-grid,
  .flex-grid-thirds {
    display: block;
  }
  .flex-grid-thirds .col {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  }
}


}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.flex-grid {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Inlämningsuppgift 6</title>
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <!--nav bar-->
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li style="list-style: none"><br></li>
   <li><img alt="htmll logo" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"></li>
   <li>
    <h2>Menu</h2>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="active" href="#lank">Länk 1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#lank2">Länk 2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#lank3">Länk 3</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#lank4">Länk 4</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav><!--navbar end-->
 <!--container for blog posts 3 images-->

 </div>
 <div class="container">

  <h1>Innehåll</h1>
  <div class="flex-grid-thirds">
   <div class="col">
       <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alligment >
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div><!--end-->
 <hr>
 <!--container for article -->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="article-container clearfix">
   <img alt="html logo" class="wrap align-right" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
   <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
   <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
 </div><!--end-->
 <footer class="container">
  Skriven i HTML 5.
 </footer>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the class .col is still set to width 32%. When the browser is less than 480px the body text is still only 32% when it should be 100%.

Easiest fix is to add

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .col {
        width: 100% !important;

    }

}
```

If you want to remove the !important you can move the class .flex-grid-thirds .col to only get called when the browser is greater than 481px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {

    {
        width: 32%;
    }

}
```